# Create a series of dates in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.3, series

I am trying to [generate a series](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html) of `DATE` objects for each day since January 1st, 2014.

The following query works:

```SQL
SELECT day::DATE FROM
  (SELECT
     generate_series('2014-01-01'::DATE, now(), '1 day') as day) sq;
    day
------------
 2014-01-01
 2014-01-02
 2014-01-03
 2014-01-04
 2014-01-05
 2014-01-06
 2014-01-07
 2014-01-08
 2014-01-09
 2014-01-10
 2014-01-11
 2014-01-12
 ...
 2015-12-13
 2015-12-14
 2015-12-15
(714 rows)
```

However, the subquery seems inelegant to me. Is there a way to create the date objects directly from the `generate_series` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select day::date
from generate_series('2014-01-01'::date, now(), '1 day') sq (day)
```

Or directly in the select list:

```
select generate_series('2014-01-01'::date, now(), '1 day')::date as day
```

Comment: Spot on, amigo. Thanks!